# Rest API import product Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, rest-api

I want to add a product using REST API but don't know how should I do.
could you please help me what should I do? Magento 2.1 I use. this is the code that i used:

```
{
    "id": 989898989989989898,
    "sku": "5",
    "name": "simple test",
    "attribute_set_id": 23,
    "price": 25000,
    "status": 1,
    "visibility": 4,
    "type_id": "simple",
    "created_at": "2019-07-02 11:00:15",
    "updated_at": "2019-07-02 11:50:25",
    "weight": 10,
    "extension_attributes": {
        "stock_item": {
            "item_id": 998989898989898,
            "product_id": 98989898989899898989898,
            "stock_id": 1,
            "qty": 5,
            "is_in_stock": true,
            "is_qty_decimal": false,
            "show_default_notification_message": false,
            "use_config_min_qty": true,
            "min_qty": 0,
            "use_config_min_sale_qty": 1,
            "min_sale_qty": 1,
            "use_config_max_sale_qty": true,
            "max_sale_qty": 10000,
            "use_config_backorders": true,
            "backorders": 0,
            "use_config_notify_stock_qty": true,
            "notify_stock_qty": 1,
            "use_config_qty_increments": true,
            "qty_increments": 0,
            "use_config_enable_qty_inc": true,
            "enable_qty_increments": false,
            "use_config_manage_stock": false,
            "manage_stock": true,
            "low_stock_date": null,
            "is_decimal_divided": false,
            "stock_status_changed_auto": 0
        }
    },
    "product_links": [],
    "options": [],
    "media_gallery_entries": [
        {
            "id": 6034,
            "media_type": "image",
            "label": null,
            "position": 1,
            "disabled": false,
            "types": [
                "small_image",
                "thumbnail",
                "swatch_image"
            ],
            "file": "/1/5/87987.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 6035,
            "media_type": "image",
            "label": null,
            "position": 2,
            "disabled": false,
            "types": [],
            "file": "/1/5/656565.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "tier_prices": [],
    "custom_attributes": [
        {
            "attribute_code": "description",
            "value": "<ul><li>des test</li></ul>"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "short_description",
            "value": "<ul><li>shhort desc</ul>"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "small_image",
            "value": "/1/5/1540017-5714-7100451-3.jpg"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "thumbnail",
            "value": "/1/5/1540017-5714-7100451-3.jpg"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "category_ids",
            "value": [
                "418",
                "419",
                "2256",
                "2257"
            ]
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "options_container",
            "value": "container1"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "required_options",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "has_options",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "msrp_display_actual_price_type",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "url_key",
            "value": "4"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "gift_message_available",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
            "value": "2"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "swatch_image",
            "value": "/1/5/1540017-5714-7100451-3.jpg"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "sm_featured",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "udropship_calculate_rates",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "udropship_vendor",
            "value": "5"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "udtiership_use_custom",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "udtiership_rates",
            "value": [
                {
                    "rate_id": "5",
                    "product_id": "4036",
                    "delivery_type_id": "13",
                    "customer_shipclass_id": "475",
                    "customer_group_id": "*",
                    "cost": "222000.0000",
                    "additional": "0.0000",
                    "handling": "0.0000",
                    "sort_order": "0"
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

but get below error

```
{
    "message": "%fieldName is a required field.",
    "parameters": {
        "fieldName": "product"
    }
}
```

on this URL

```
/rest/default/V1/products
```

Comment: Please check below I answered, You can loop for import products. only this endpoint "/V1/products" do loop.

Answer (score 0):

**Here you can create all types of products, I gave for simple product creation. You can check Magento swagger and You can change only input data js format**

> https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_22.html

```
 <?php
   $url="http://xx.xx.xx.xx/magentoc23/index.php/";
  <!-- start code,here we are creating Authentication --> 
   $token_url=$url."rest/V1/integration/admin/token";
   $username="adminusername";
   $password="adminpassword";

   $data = array("username" => $username, "password" => $password);
   $data_string = json_encode($data);

   $ch = curl_init($token_url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
     'Content-Type: application/json',
     'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
     );
   $token = curl_exec($ch);
   $adminToken=  json_decode($token);
<!------------------- end code------------> 


  <!-- start code, here we are creating products and we can loop from here to --> 

   $product_data = '{"product": 
  {"sku":"sss11","name":"sss11","attribute_set_id":4,"price":60}}';
  //Here product_data we have to read data from csv file.If you need data format means check in swagger

   $setHaders = array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization:Bearer 
    '.$adminToken);
    $product_url=$url. "rest/V1/products";  //This is endpoint for create all products, you have to change input Data.

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $product_url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $product_data);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $setHaders);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $response = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 var_dump($response);
<!----------- end code------------>
```

Comment: Could you explain me step by step what should i do from first till last?

Comment: Hi MGPM, I kept comments in the above code. IF you have more then 1000 records means, you have to use BULK rest API in Magento 2.3.0 version. We are using the Bulk API in our project Magento 2.3.0

Comment: Updated my question...

Answer (score 0):

For Adding the product through Rest API, you need to add the body content inside the "product" array element.

**URL:- /rest//V1/products eg. http://127.0.0.1/magento/rest/V1/products**

**Method:- POST**

**Header part :Authorization: Bearer 
Content-Type:   application/json**

**Enter Payload like these**

```
{
  "product": {
    "sku": "samsung-a50",
    "name": "Samsung A50 ",
    "attribute_set_id": 4,
    "price": 150000,
    "status": 1,
    "visibility": 1,
    "type_id": "Default",
    "weight": "1",
    "extension_attributes": {
      "category_links": [
        {
          "position": 0,
          "category_id": "6"
        }
      ],
      "stock_item": {
        "qty": "10",
        "is_in_stock": true
      }
    },
    "custom_attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_code": "pattern",
        "value": "1960"
      },
      {
        "attribute_code": "color",
        "value": "45"
      },
      {
        "attribute_code": "size",
        "value": "168"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```